# How do I get the correct values from glReadPixels in OpenGL 3.0?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm currently trying to Implement mouse selection into my game editor and I ran into a little problem when I look at the values stored in `&pixel[0],&pixel[1],&pixel[2],&pixel[3];` I get

```
r: 0
g: 0
b: 0
a: 0
```

As you can see I'm not able to get the correct values from `glReadPixels();`

My 3D models are red colored using `glColor3f(255,0,0);`

I was hoping someone could help me figure this out.

Here is the source code:

```
  case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:

  {

    GetCursorPos(&pos);
    ScreenToClient(hwnd, &pos);

     GLenum err = glGetError();

     while (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR) {cerr << err << endl;}

     glReadPixels(pos.x, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1 - pos.y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixel[0] );

    cerr << "r: "<< (int)pixel[0] << endl;
    cerr << "g: "<< (int)pixel[1] << endl;
    cerr << "b: "<< (int)pixel[2] << endl;
    cerr << "a: "<< (int)pixel[3] << endl;

    cout << pos.x << endl;
    cout << pos.y << endl;

  }

break;
```

I use :

```
WIN32 API
OPENGL 3.0
C++
```

Comment: It doesn't seem you are binding the frame buffer before calling glReadPixels. http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object

Comment: I've posted an example at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36236839/895245

Answer (score 2):

FBOs shouldn't be relevant in this case as it's happening outside of the main render.

glReadPixels definitely works as advertised in this kind of setup - I just copied and pasted your code into a program and got expected results.  That indicates to me that your problem is most likely elsewhere.

You should check the current value of glReadBuffer - if it's not GL_BACK then you may not get the end result you want.  Also check that you're not doing anything weird like creating a single-buffered context.

Check your value of SCREEN_HEIGHT - is it actually the height of your window's client rect?  If not then the read will be off-location.  At this point I have to bring up the fact that the size you create your window at is not necessarily the size of your client rect - if you're running in a windowed mode then the size params you pass to CreateWindow(Ex) will be inclusive of title bar, borders, etc.  You may already be aware of this - ignore if so.

You're not showing the definition of your "pixel" variable - "unsigned char pixel[4]" is what it should be here.  Check that too.

Purely cosmetic but you don't need to pass "&pixel[0]" as your data parameter.  Just "pixel" will do.

Reading as GL_RGB won't give you a meaningful value in your alpha channel (which you may not have anyway if your pixel format doesn't have destination alpha) - use GL_RGBA instead.

Also cosmetic, but I'm not certain what you're trying to achieve with that glGetError loop - glGetError doesn't behave like that, and you're not going to get meaningful or helpful info from it.

Comment: According to the docs, glGetError() yields one error kind at a time per call. He seems to have lost the part where he should check for new errors after his function.

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetError.xml - the error flag is set when an error occurs and no other errors are recorded until it's cleared (by a call to glGetError) so multiple successive calls to glGetError with no other GL calls between them will achieve nothing; only the first call is of value.  In this case the first call will give a valid result, but the subsequent calls (in the while loop) are meaningless - also, the loop will never run (and never output an error) because the first call (outside the loop) will have cleared the error flag.

Comment: Ah, it seems that this code is slightly different from the one he tried to get help for on IRC. Yay for shotgunning questions at _all_ the places at once.

Comment: Interesting about `glGetError()`. At some point, I too learned that there could be more than one and you needed to loop over it. I wonder why I was taught that?